# root user on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, root

I created a new user on my server, with:

`useradd newuser`

Then tried to set the login shell and group for the user afterwards, but seems I did something wrong.
Now when I try to switch to root user I get:

> Cannot execute newuser: No such file or directory

for command:

`cat /etc/passwd | grep root`

I get:

> root:x:0:0:root:/root:newuser

Is there a way to set things straight from here?
Are the commands I ran needed to understand what the solution may be?
I still have the command history in my console

Comment: Write whatever you have done, /etc/passwd last field will be your login shell, you have changed from `default shell` (such as /bin/bas) to `newuser`, since `newuser` doesn't exists it is giving you error.

Comment: @asktyagi,
Thanks for your help, but Mircea Vutcovici's answer helped me find the solution, as I wrote below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to boot from a rescue CD and mount `/` volume and edit `/etc/passwd` and change the entry for shell from `newuser` to `/bin/bash`.
For more details see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

Comment: Thank you for the advice, this is a virtual server on Digitalocean.
I'm trying now from [digitaloceans recovery iso function](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/resources/recovery-iso/).

Comment: Thank you so much @mircea-vutcovici!
I was able to log in to my server with the recovery ISO possibility and modify the /etc/passwd line you brought to my attention!
This was a true lifesaver, since I wasn't expecting to do anything serious, I didn't make a backup before creating the problem. My last backup was 2 months old.

Thank you, thank you and thank you once more!!!